# How to take HTML code as input in URL(using $_REQUEST)

Tags: php, html

I am using an API which takes url,id,offset,guide,output like

```
$uri = trim(urldecode($_REQUEST['uri']));
$web_service_id = trim($_REQUEST['id']);
$guide = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['guide']));
$output = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['output']))
$offset = intval($_REQUEST['offset']);
```

I am passing all these values in url like :

```
http://localhost:8000/master/checkacc.php?uri=http://www.example.com/us& id=d9&output=html&guide=508&offset=0
```

After this it uses the url to get the source code like

```
$validate_content = @file_get_contents($uri);
```

But instead of getting source code from url I want to pass the HTML/Source code myself using a parameter named 'html'.
So I did this:

```
$validate_content = ($_REQUEST['html']);
```

Now I am trying :

```
http://localhost:8000/master/checkacc.php?uri=http://www.example.com/us& id=d9&output=html&guide=508&offset=0 & html="PASTE HTML CODE HERE "
```

It is working fine for small html codes but for long html codes it is taking only few lines of the HTML code and escaping after few lines. 
How to take HTML CODE as input in url.

Comment: Url's are restricted by length. If you want to process a lot of data in a request, you should consider using a POST request and having the content in the body of the request.

Comment: You should correctly encode the values you want to pass through the url. And even then there is only a limited amount of data you can send through the url / using GET.

Comment: @TZHX It means you are saying I should use the old url as it is use this: 
$validate_url = $_POST['html'].
.

Comment: @jeroen I have tried encoding the values but for html it is taking 50-60 characters only

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a server configuration. If you're working with PHP under Linux or similar, you can control it using .htaccess configuration file, like so:

## set max post size

## php_value post_max_size 20M.

I achieved the same goal using $_POST(which I think is better way)
`trim(urldecode(($_POST["html"]))`